# Django - get in template reverse related many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have 3 models, Entry model and Category model, and I have created intermediate model CategoryEntry.

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    entries = models.ManyToManyField(Entry, through='CategoryEntry')

class CategoryEntry(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have created a View with get_queryset method like this

```
    def get_queryset(self):
    order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by')

    if not order_by:
        order_by = '-pub_date'

    return Entry.objects.filter(category__id=self.kwargs.get('category_id', None), category__user__id=self.request.user.id).order_by(order_by)[:].select_related('user')
```

I have category ID from kwargs. The problem is - how to get every entries related field "viewed", so I can show its value in template. For example related User field I can get like

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.entry_text }}
    {{ entry.user.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

What I need is to access "viewed" field something like "entry.categoryentry.viewed"

Tried prefetch_related, but doesn't seem to work or don't get how to know right name to access field in template

```
Entry.objects.filter(category__id=self.kwargs.get('category_id', None), category__user__id=self.request.user.id).order_by(order_by)[:].select_related('user').prefetch_related(Prefetch("categoryentry_set", queryset=CategoryEntry.objects.filter(category__id=self.kwargs.get('category_id', None))))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.entry_text }}
    {{ entry.user.name }}
    {% for ce in entry.catalogentry_set.all %}
        {{ce.category.category_text}} 
        {# or whatever.. #}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Basically, if no `related_name` is present, you could access the reverse lookup element by `lowercase model name + _set` - which returns a queryset manager object.

Comment: it should be {% endfor %} instand of {% endif %}.I can't make a correction because it is too little changes, sorry.